# How to override click event on AddThis button

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook, addthis, facebook-share

I have a challenge that I haven't been able to solve.

AddThis provides a button to share to Facebook.  My page uses AJAX to dynamically change the page based on user interaction.  I have working code to move the AddThis toolbar to the appropriate spot, and update the title, image, and URL in AddThis.

The problem is AddThis is calling Facebook with apparently obsolete URL parameters to pass the title, image, and URL.  As such, Facebook doesn't see any of the parms and the share popup contains the wrong data.

I've tried using the opengraph (`og`) tags, however Facebook seems incapable of seeing the updated `og` tags that are dynamically updated via AJAX.

I've found the Facebook API code to manually trigger the share popup, which works great.  The challenge is tying that code to the AddThis facebook button event, and not the other AddThis buttons, so that clicking it triggers my code instead of the AddThis code.

Looking at the Chrome developer tools, it appears the click isn't caught on the Facebook `<a>` button itself, but the parent div, as I see code on `div#atstbx`.

I'm able to locate the AddThis facebook button using `jQuery('a[class="at-icon-wrapper at-share-btn at-svc-facebook"]')`, however adding something to `click()` doesn't appear to do anything (probably because it's an `<a>` button).  As such, calling `stopPropagation()` doesn't work, as `click` doesn't appear to be called.

How do I change what happens on the clicking on the `<a>` facebook addthis button to my code?

I'm thinking I can change the callback on `div#atstbx` to my own routine, check to see which button is clicked, and then call the original function or my function as necessary.  However I don't know how to do that.

Thank you in advance! :)

P.S. I'd prefer use the dynamic AddThis toolbar as opposed to specific buttons and hard coding my own buttons in AddThis.

Comment: also interested in this...have the same problem. Have you found any solution @Mmm?

Comment: My solution was to no longer use AddThis.